# Grunt Task > Minify inline Json-ld script in html file > Jekyll Build

Tags: gruntjs, inline, minify, json-ld

**SHORT VERSION**

Is there a grunt task which will minify inline json wrapped in `<script type="application/ld+json">` tags in an html file?

---

**LONG VERSION**

I am using jekyll and grunt.

The Jekyll build creates static html files with page/post specific inline json-ld.

The json-ld is wrapped in `<script type="application/ld+json">` tags.

I want to minify the entire HTML file.

I have run **grunt-contrib-htmlmin** (htmlmin) on the files.

Htmlmin has nicely minified all content:

1. before the `<script type="application/ld+json">` tag into 1 line; and
2. after the `<script type="application/ld+json">` tag into 1 line.

The `<script type="application/ld+json">` tag and its contents has been ignored.

Htmlmin has an option called MinifyJS to *"Minify Javascript in script elements and on* attributes (uses UglifyJS)"*.

I have tried the option as both true and false, and without the option altogether. The json-ld tag is still ignored.

I have tested the json-ld syntax in an online minifier. It returned the code (~100 lines) as one line.

I have searched for other Grunt tasks. It looks like there are a few other html minifiers out there but none seem as well developed and supported as grunt-contrib-htmlmin. I suspect that they will have the same issue but I will consider testing some others if I do not get a response.

I am new to Grunt.

Can anyone suggest a Grunt task that can handle this?

Or provide guidance on how to do this?

Thank you for any assistance in advance! :)

Answer (score 2):

I won a tumble weed award for this (yay), but even better: I have an answer!

**Grunt-contrib-htmlmin** has an option called `processScripts` to specify script types for processing. By specifying `application/ld+json`, you will force it to process the Json-LD too.

This is probably obvious to most, and it is to me now, but it wasn't to me when I first asked this. Goes to show that once you understand something you are better addressed at coming up with solutions - and my steep "coding" learning curve is finally paying off!